# CALayer mask Layer animating

Tags: uikit, core-animation, calayer, cashapelayer

I want to mask CALayer with another layer whose frame I want to keep changing in every draw call thereby animating. Is it possible to do change the frame of mask layer in every draw call rather than making a new mask layer?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. This code will run on Cocoa App for macOS. Kindly change the classes accordingly if you are going for Cocoa Touch for iOS. I hope this works for you.

//  ViewController.h

## import

@interface ViewController : NSViewController{

```
CALayer * maskLayer;
CALayer * Layer;
```

}

//  ViewController.m

@implementation ViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad{

```
[super viewDidLoad];

maskLayer = [CALayer layer];
Layer = [CALayer layer];

Layer.backgroundColor = [[NSColor blueColor] CGColor];
Layer.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 720, 900);
Layer.contents = [NSImage imageNamed:@"bg1"];

maskLayer.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 720, 900);
maskLayer.opacity = 0.5;
[maskLayer mask];

maskLayer.contents = [NSImage imageNamed:@"bg"];


[self.view.layer addSublayer:Layer];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:maskLayer];

[self maskLayerAnimation];
```

}

-(void)maskLayerAnimation{

```
[CATransaction begin];
CABasicAnimation* fadeAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
fadeAnim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
fadeAnim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
fadeAnim.duration = 5.0;


[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"animation completed");
    maskLayer.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 720, 700);
    maskLayer.contents = [NSImage imageNamed:@"bg2"];
}];;

[maskLayer addAnimation:fadeAnim forKey:@"opacity"];
[CATransaction commit];
```

}